# Change WORDPRESS permalinks Structure to use Custom Field Values Dynamically for Custom Post Types

Tags: php, wordpress, permalinks, custom-fields

I am using Custom Post type 'listing' and in these post type i have Custom Field Values geocraft_state and geocraft_city.

Currently links are as follows

site.com/listing/Title-of-listing

but i want them to be like this

http://site.com/geocraft_state/geocraft_city/Title-of-Listing

so if someone from NA State post a listing the link should be as follows

site.com/NA/Greensboro/Title-of-Listing

Is their anyway we can use Dynamically Custom Fields Value to generate links?

Any Help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using Custom Fields i added custom taxonomy for location by adding these codes in functions.php. Now i have to figure out how to show this in Front End Form.

```
function add_custom_taxonomies() {
    // Add new "Locations" taxonomy to Posts
    register_taxonomy('location', 'post', array(
        // Hierarchical taxonomy (like categories)
        'hierarchical' => true,
        // This array of options controls the labels displayed in the WordPress Admin UI
        'labels' => array(
            'name' => _x( 'Locations', 'taxonomy general name' ),
            'singular_name' => _x( 'Location', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
            'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Locations' ),
            'all_items' => __( 'All Locations' ),
            'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Location' ),
            'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Location:' ),
            'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Location' ),
            'update_item' => __( 'Update Location' ),
            'add_new_item' => __( 'Add New Location' ),
            'new_item_name' => __( 'New Location Name' ),
            'menu_name' => __( 'Locations' ),
        ),
        // Control the slugs used for this taxonomy
        'rewrite' => array(
            'slug' => 'locations', // This controls the base slug that will display before each term
            'with_front' => false, // Don't display the category base before "/locations/"
            'hierarchical' => true // This will allow URL's like "/locations/boston/cambridge/"
        ),
    ));
}
add_action( 'init', 'add_custom_taxonomies', 0 );
```

Comment: If you want to show the custom terms in your template, split-ed by comma, and with link to the term, you just have to add `<?php echo get_the_term_list( $post->ID, 'location', '', ', ', '' ); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

The fastest and easiest way with almost 0 coding to do this is to stop using Custom Fields, and set all those fields as Taxonomies \ Categories, hierarchical categories in which geocraft_state would have geocraft_city as children, and using the permalink structure as `/%category%/%postname%/`

More about taxonomies here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Taxonomies

Comment: Thanks for your response , There are so many states and cities around the world it will be really hard for me to add all of them as category, is their any function which auto adds that specific Custom field added by user to convert into category and city as sub-category?

Comment: I'm thinking that you still have to manually write those custom fields. There is a plugin that auto-transforms custom fields to categories / taxonomies: http://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-field-taxonomies/ You can also, assign the first tag as the category with `wp_set_post_categories( $post_ID, $post_categories )` and then the child, the other custom meta with the same function, checking before with ` <?php term_exists( $term, $taxonomy, $parent ) ?> ` and if not, set them `<?php wp_set_post_terms( $post_id, $terms, $taxonomy, $append ) ?>` accordingly to parent/child